# Radius Query with vender radius restrictions

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following radius query below. The first select will get me every record within 4 miles. (just to keep things simple, the zip in this example is just a primary key and should not be thought of as an actual zip. I'm just trying to model this as a vendor within a given long/lat.)

5 records are returned within 4 miles of latitude 43 and longitude- -74.37

What I'm looking to do is once the records are found, then do a reverse select on the records found using the restriction column as my new radius restriction to eliminate records where vendors do not want to be found outside a particular distance from their physical location.

In my query example below, I'm expecting to find all results except fonda 12068 because that record although is within 4 miles of the first select only wants to be visible within 1 mile (restriction column) of his physical location. The image however is the actual results produced. Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

My thought was I could use the the long/lat along with the restriction from the result of the first query to see if a zip was returned matching the original zip.

```
SELECT zip1.* FROM zip_detail as zip1 
    WHERE (3958*3.1415926*sqrt((latitude-43)*(latitude-43) 
    + cos(latitude/57.29578)*cos(43/57.29578)
    *(longitude- -74.37)*(longitude- -74.37))/180) 
    <= 4

and zip1.zip in (SELECT zip2.zip FROM zip_detail as zip2 
    WHERE (3958*3.1415926*sqrt((latitude-zip1.latitude)*(latitude-zip1.latitude) 
    + cos(latitude/57.29578)*cos(zip1.latitude/57.29578)
    *(longitude- zip1.longitude)*(longitude- zip1.longitude))/180) 
    <= zip1.restriction)
```

[image]

I created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bad9e/1) example

Comment: <= LEAST(4,restriction)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand could you please explain thanks

Comment: Well, replace <= 4 with what I wrote. Seems fairly straightforward, right?

Comment: Do I leave the subquery?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bad9e/4

Comment: Worked like a charm, if you could answer this post with an answer, I'll vote you up. I'm not a dba by any means, so it would be cool if you could explain your work a little more.

Comment: It seems a little too obvious to bother!

Comment: Its odvious when you have a strong database background ;) btw would you happen to know how to make something this work with elasticsearch? I'm not sure if those engines provide this kind of capability.

Comment: Sorry but I've no idea what that is! I'm OK with MySQL queries, but not much else that you might find on StackOverflow